# MySQL 8 installation fail - dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:

Tags: software-installation, mysql, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wasn't able yet to install MySQL 8 in Ubuntu.

- Distribution : Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (running on windows using WSL)
- WSL version : 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
- Mysql-server : 8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04 amd64

I am following these instructions - [Steps for a fresh installation of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install)

Deb Package downloaded : (mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb)

I have tried some suggestions that I found at the internet, based on similar cases, but none of them worked. Example : `sudo apt -f install` -> In order to fix the dependency problem.

After the installation, I run the command to start the mysql server, but the service isn't recognized, so the installation fail.

Based on my experience, it's very hard to evaluate exactly the root cause of the problem, any suggestion recommendation and suggestion would be really appreciated.

I am planning to follow this installation process My SQL Community Server, https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/, where I can select the packages to be installed.

---

### Installed MySql Packages after installation process finishes

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql -> Installed Packages

ii  mysql-apt-config               0.8.13-1                           all          Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
ii  mysql-client                   8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        MySQL Client meta package depending on latest version
ii  mysql-common                   8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        Common files shared between packages
ii  mysql-community-client         8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        MySQL Client
ii  mysql-community-client-core    8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        MySQL Client Core Binaries
iF  mysql-community-server         8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        MySQL Server
ii  mysql-community-server-core    8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        MySQL Server Core Binaires
iU  mysql-server                   8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04                amd64        MySQL Server meta package depending on latest version
```

---

### Installation output :

```
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server-core (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27327
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Best Regards,
Ricardo

I followed the recommendations of the other question, but it didn't work, but I agree that the question is duplicated.

Comment: sudo apt install mysql-server didn´t work, same result as apt-get provided into mysql installation instructions.

Comment: sorry my lack of knowledge, I am a beginner, which command I can use to check corrupted dependencies? I did dpkg-reconfigure mysql-community-server && dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server but it didn´t work

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful link : https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3631, @jw-redpanda put some light in my problem. He mentions a installation problem at MySql 8.0 using WSL in windows. The MySQl doesn´t start. He presents a workaround, well for me I was able to install version 5.7 at least, but I wasn't able to proceed after step 5, when you have the version 8 as candidate.  It worked for others, so good luck for you.

Answer (score 0):

Under WSL 2 (and I'm presuming WSL 1) systemd is not available as a default, and init.d scripts are not run at startup.

What's more, if you install MySQL 8 from the deb package here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ the default mysql.server helper script that is used to start or stop MySQL won't be installed.

One solution is to download the mysql.server.sh script from here - https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/support-files and then copy and rename the script to /etc/init.d/mysql (make sure that it's also executable - chmod +x mysql)

You'll then need to set the default values for basdir, datadir and pid file locations.

Here's a full write up along with a few other tips... https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/05/03/installing-mysql-80-under-wsl-2-and-ubuntu